# Convert json dynamic content to C# object (or dictionary)

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "content1": {
                "prop1" : "value1",
                "prop2" : "value2"
            },
            "content2": {
                "prop1" : "value1",
                "prop2" : "value2"
            },
            "contentn": {
                "prop1" : "value1",
                "prop2" : "value2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am having trouble converting this json to a dynamic C# object, the case here is that 'content1' to 'content' will always be different and dynamic content and I do need to convert it to something like a dictionary.
The idea is to reduce the classes as, I will need to create tons of them.

PS: I am using a 3rd party api that's returning the data as above.

Tried numerous ways to handle this.
`JsonConvert` to try to map to `Dictionary`, `List` and the same for `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`

Comment: Powershell has some nice features that will make this task easier.

Comment: Using Newtonsoft.Json you could just use `JObject.Parse` for example... that provides various ways of querying the data. (There's definitely no need to go into PowerShell for this...)

Comment: Using System.Text.Json you could use `JsonDocument.Parse`.

Comment: Use `System.Text.Json` for your solution. Other libraries are outdated or have security issues.

Comment: @SanjnaMalpani that's a bold claim. Do you consider Newtonsoft.Json outdated and having security issues?

Answer (score 4):

The solution below uses [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-7.0)

Create a `Content` class:

```
public class Content
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

and now you can deserialize:

```
var data = "{\r\n    \"results\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"content1\": {\r\n                \"prop1\" : \"value1\",\r\n                \"prop2\" : \"value2\"\r\n            },\r\n            \"content2\": {\r\n                \"prop1\" : \"value1\",\r\n                \"prop2\" : \"value2\"\r\n            },\r\n            \"contentn\": {\r\n                \"prop1\" : \"value1\",\r\n                \"prop2\" : \"value2\"\r\n            }\r\n        }\r\n    ]\r\n}";

var serData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<object>>>(data);
var myResults = serData.First().Value[0].ToString();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myResults))
{
    var myDynamicObjects = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Content>>(myResults);
}
```

Comment: Flat out rude - OP already tried that "Tried numerous ways to handle this. JsonConvert to try to map to Dictionary, List and the same for JsonSerializer.Deserialize".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov how is it rude? **OP:** "I do need to convert it to something like a dictionary. The idea is to reduce the classes as I will need to create tons of them." The solution provides the creation of one class, which can again be an `object`, but I prefer having at least one.

Comment: problem is that the list of properties is not fixed, so it cannot be mapped to a single statically typed class

Comment: If the list is not fixed then it can be mapped to an `object`. However, if the list is not fixed why deserialize and map it? Let it all be a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-7.0) very powerfull for that kind of jobs.

```
static async Task Main(string[] _)
{
    var dynamicReturn = await new HttpClient().GetFromJsonAsync<ExpandoObject>("https://run.mocky.io/v3/dab5a150-40a9-4520-a809-ff5484489fe9");

    foreach (var kvp in dynamicReturn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
// using Newtonsoft.Json;

Dictionary<string, Content>  content = JObject.Parse(json)["results"][0]
                                          .ToObject<Dictionary<string, Content>>();
 //or
// using System.Text.Json

Dictionary<string, Content> content = System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode
                                     .Parse(json)["results"][0]
                                     .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Content>>();
```

class

```
public class Content
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this::**

```
public class Content
{
    public string Prop1{ get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Content>>('your json data');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).